# form have to click submit twice before success message in php

Tags: php

I am trying to do a reservation/booking page, so I have a form that gets information from the user and details about the services that they would like and add it to the database. I can insert records with no problems, like the record gets recorded only once and a success message if the data get inserted successfully and a fail message if otherwise should follow. The problem is the message would display after clicking the submit button twice or after the page refreshes.

This is how the code of the message looks:

```
    if ($res_bookings){
        
        $_SESSION['done'] = "<h2 class='success'>BOOKED SUCCESSFULLY</h2>";
       
    } else {
        $_SESSION['done'] = "<h2 class='failed'>BOOKING FAILED</h2>";
    }
```

And for the whole php code

```
<?php

//to get data from form

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //assign values
    $customer_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['customer_name']);
    $customer_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn ,$_POST['customer_number']);
    $customer_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['customer_email']);
    $event_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event']);
    $start = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_start']);
    $end = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_end']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_address']);
    $menus = $_POST['menu'];
    $extras = $_POST['extra'];
    $booking_id = rand(000, 999);
    $event_id = rand(000, 999);
    $payment_id = rand(000, 999);
    
    //no empty values to be inserted in database
    if($customer_name == ""){
        $_SESSION['name'] = "<p class='failed'>PLEASE FILL NAME</p>";

        die();
    }

    if($customer_number == "" && $customer_email == ""){
        $_SESSION['contacts'] = "<p class='failed'>PLEASE FILL CONTACTS</p>";

        die();
    }

    if(empty($menus) || empty($extras)){
        $_SESSION['menu'] = "<p class='failed'>PLEASE PICK YOUR MENU OR EXTRAS</p>";

        die();
    }


     ////for storing event details to event_details table
    $query = "INSERT INTO event_details
        SET id = ?,
        startTime = ?,
        endTime = ?,
        eventAddress = ?,
        event_type = (
            SELECT id 
            FROM events
            WHERE id = ?);";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("isssi", $event_id, $start, $end, $address, $event_type);
    $res_event = $stmt->execute();

    if (!$res_event){
        echo $conn->error;
    }

    //create booking record
    $query_2 = "INSERT INTO bookings
        SET id = ?,
        customer_name = ?,
        customer_contact_no = ?,
        customer_email = ?,
        eventID = (
            SELECT id
            FROM event_details
            WHERE id = ?);";

    $stmt_2 = $conn->prepare($query_2);
    $stmt_2->bind_param("isssi", $booking_id, $customer_name, $customer_number, $customer_email, $event_id);
    $res_book = $stmt_2->execute();
    
    if (!$res_book){
        echo $conn->error;
    }
    
    //create menu record
    $menu_query = "INSERT INTO menus_bookings
        SET
        bookingID = (
            SELECT id
            FROM bookings
            WHERE id = ?),
        type = (
            SELECT id
            FROM menus_types
            WHERE id = ?);";

    $menu_stmt = $conn->prepare($menu_query);
    $menu_stmt->bind_param("ii", $booking_id, $menu);

    foreach ($menus as $menu){
       $res_menu = $menu_stmt->execute();
    }

    if(!$res_menu){
        echo $conn->error;
    }

    ///create extras record
    $extras_query = "INSERT INTO extras_bookings
        SET
        bookingID = (
            SELECT id
            FROM bookings
            WHERE id = ?),
        type = (
            SELECT id
            FROM extras_types
            WHERE id = ?);";

    $extras_stmt = $conn->prepare($extras_query);
    $extras_stmt->bind_param("ii", $booking_id, $extra);

    foreach ($extras as $extra){
        $res_extras = $extras_stmt->execute();
    }


     if(!$res_extras){
         echo $conn->error;
     }

    //calculate fees
    $menu_sql = "SELECT SUM(mt.price) as 'menu total'
    FROM menus_types mt, menus_bookings mb
    WHERE mt.id = mb.type
    AND mb.bookingID = ?;";

    $stmt_menu = $conn->prepare($menu_sql);
    $stmt_menu->bind_param("i", $booking_id);
    $stmt_menu->execute();
    $result_menu = $stmt_menu->get_result();
    $row_menu = $result_menu->fetch_assoc();
    $menu_total = $row_menu['menu total'];

    $extras_sql = "SELECT SUM(et.price) as 'extras total'
    FROM extras_types et, extras_bookings eb
    WHERE et.id = eb.type
    AND eb.bookingID = ?;";

    $stmt_extras = $conn->prepare($extras_sql);
    $stmt_extras->bind_param("i", $booking_id);
    $stmt_extras->execute();
    $result_extras = $stmt_extras->get_result();
    $row_extras = $result_extras->fetch_assoc();
    $extras_total = $row_extras['extras total'];

    $total = $menu_total + $extras_total;
    $min = $total * .50;

    //create payment details
    $query_pay = "INSERT INTO payment_details
        SET id = ?,
        extras_total = ?,
        menus_total = ?,
        total = ?,
        minPayment = ?;
      ";

    $stmt_pay = $conn->prepare($query_pay);
    $stmt_pay->bind_param("iiiii", $payment_id, $extras_total, $menu_total, $total, $min);
    $res_pay = $stmt_pay->execute();

    if(!$res_pay){
        echo $conn->error;
    } 

    //add receipt to booking record
    $query_booking = "UPDATE bookings
        SET receiptID = (
            SELECT id 
            FROM payment_details
            WHERE id = ?)
        WHERE id = ?;
      ";

    $stmt_bookings = $conn->prepare($query_booking);
    $stmt_bookings->bind_param("ii", $payment_id, $booking_id);
    $res_bookings = $stmt_bookings->execute();

    if ($res_bookings){
        
        $_SESSION['done'] = "<h2 class='success'>BOOKED SUCCESSFULLY</h2>";
        
    } else {
        $_SESSION['done'] = "<h2 class='failed'>BOOKING FAILED</h2>";
    }
}
?>
```

I am not used to using PHP at all, but I think the issue is in the PHP part and not in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing this data to the $_SESSION variable and not actually outputting it to the page.

If you wish to show the success message after the form is submitted just use:

```
if ($res_bookings) {
    echo "<h2 class='success'>BOOKED SUCCESSFULLY</h2>";
} else {
    echo "<h2 class='failed'>BOOKING FAILED</h2>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

change this last part of your code:

```
    $stmt_bookings = $conn->prepare($query_booking);
    $stmt_bookings->bind_param("ii", $payment_id, $booking_id);
    $res_bookings = $stmt_bookings->execute();

    if ($res_bookings){
        
        $_SESSION['done'] = "<h2 class='success'>BOOKED SUCCESSFULLY</h2>";
        
    } else {
        $_SESSION['done'] = "<h2 class='failed'>BOOKING FAILED</h2>";
    }
}
```

to this :

```
    $stmt_bookings = $conn->prepare($query_booking);
    $stmt_bookings->bind_param("ii", $payment_id, $booking_id);
    $res_bookings = $stmt_bookings->execute();
        
    $_SESSION['done'] = "<h2 class='success'>BOOKED SUCCESSFULLY</h2>";
        
    } else {
        
     $_SESSION['done'] = "<h2 class='failed'>BOOKING FAILED</h2>";
    
}
```

which means immediately after code execution, success message will be displayed else failed message appears.

Comment: There are syntax errors here. You have an else with no if?

Comment: why are you in such a hurry to correct someone?  re-read my answer again, i just ask him to change some part of the code which i quoted ,look at the whole code he posted you will understand